# Change project Name Create Issue iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, project, bitbucket

I am working an iOS App having cocoaPods and stored on bitBucket, i just change the Project Name, some UI changes and pushed the code. Now problem is when my another colleague  pull the code on its own Macbook and open the workspace the project Files are absent . Any Help

Thanks
Nisar Ahmad

Comment: i think you can not change project name if you want to change your project name which displays in device that you can change. its called Product name

Comment: Because directly you were change your project name than your project directory doesn't change and your xcode does not find your project and frameworks too.